# Is it possible to port a device driver for an ISA bus peripheral from Windows XP to Windows 7 (or later)?

Tags: windows, windows-7, driver

I am aware of that this question may seem a bit quaint. I am also aware of USB to ISA adapters, but they might not be applicable in this case.

I get search results hinting about that ISA bus support was dropped after Windows XP, but what does that even mean? Shouldn't a device driver be able to access anything connected to the processor, e.g. an ISA bus controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device driver isn't the only driver needed to operate your device. In fact there is a whole bunch of drivers riding one on top of another. Your device driver is what is called a *function driver*, i.e. the driver that implements (most) of your business logic. Below the function driver there will always be a *bus driver* (unless the device is virtual) which operates the bus, which is a piece of HW on its own. So dropping the ISA bus support by the OS means there is no driver for it. Moreover, the entire ISA architecture is obsolete and doesn't integrate into the Windows 7 eco-system (so even if you had a compatible bus driver, it wouldn't be enough). In my opinion, there is not much you can do in this situation.

Comment: ISA architecture _is_ obsolete and I think your closing remark is probably right, I just want to understand this as far as possible. What do you mean by ISA architecture "doesn't integrate into the Windows 7 eco-system"? In theory, wouldn't I be able to write my own ISA bus driver for Windows 7 and port the existing function driver against this new bus driver?

Comment: @arghol I'm not an expert in this but it seems the reason is that ISA isn't a PNP architecture and latest Windows versions do not have the built-in functionality to support interaction with such devices